# Facebook iOS SDK: Retrieve User's Phone Number and Country

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I know how to properly use the Facebook iOS SDK. I have implemented posting and sharing functionalities previously so I am not shy to the matter. What, however, I would like to know is how to retrieve the user's (who connects with FB within my app) phone number and country (if not country then city).

I have read different questions and articles on how to retrieve the email and name but was just wondering if it is possible to retrieve phone number and country.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: see `Location`. And phone isn't available

Comment: Location? Is that the key. Really, with a capital L? Phone is not available. Hmmmm thats a shame...

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to get the phone #, but you can get the location through the `location` property on FBGraphUser. This will give you an object that conforms to `FBGraphPlace`. The `location` property on the `FBGraphPlace` conformer is an object that conforms to the `FBGraphLocation` protocol, which has properties such as:

- `city`
- `country`
- `latitude`
- `longitude`
- `state`
- `street`
- `zip`

Hope this helps!

Comment: THANKS LENNY, this was a while ago though :)